# The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider' reported an error despite program working

Tags: f#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, f#-data

I am writing a service using .net Core with Visual Studio 2017. I want to use JSON for the configuration, so I defined my type like this:

```
type ServiceConfig = JsonProvider<"exampleConfig.json", EmbeddedResource="MyService, exampleConfig.json", SampleIsList = true>
```

In my program, I load it like this:

```
let conf = ServiceConfig.Load "config.json"
```

When I run it, it works fine, but in VS 2017 I get a red squiggly line and the error log says:

> FS3033    The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider'
>   reported an error in the context of provided type
>   'FSharp.Data.JsonProvider,Sample="exampleConfig.json",SampleIsList="True",EmbeddedResource="MyService, exampleConfig.json"', member 'Load'. The error: Method
>   'FSharp.Data.Runtime.BaseTypes.IJsonDocument
>   Create(System.IO.TextReader, System.String)' not found in type
>   ''. This method may be missing in the types available in the
>   target assemblies.

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is the problem, but it might help to give an absolute path of the sample file. Resolving a relative path is a constant source of issues in type providers. You can do something like:

```
[<Literal>]
let sample = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/exampleConfig.json"
type ServiceConfig = 
    JsonProvider< sample, EmbeddedResource="MyService, e
                  xampleConfig.json", SampleIsList = true >
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. Same problem. I think I should put together an example reproducing this and post this on the github page.

Comment: Plus, when referencing this in a test project, the test project doesn't compile any more: `The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider' reported an error: An index satisfying the predicate was not found in the collection.`

Comment: This fixed my error when using `dotnet fsi`. Strange that it is required.

Answer (score 1):

By chance I found the answer myself. It must have been some Visual Studio index having gone wonky. I had another problem with another project in my solution so I just did an "emergency commit" to git, cleaned my local working copy using `git clean -fdx` and then reloaded the solution, rebuilt everything and the errors went away.

Comment: This saved me! I had a similar error and after half a day looking at different (and wrong) directions, I landed here.
It worked like a charm.